# Create multiple runnable Jars (with dependencies included) from a single Maven project

Tags: java, maven, executable-jar, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a single maven project that has multiple main classes. I want to generate runnable Jars (that include all dependencies) out of these project. I currently have the following build configuration (using maven.assembly):

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>classpath.to.my.mainClass</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Is their a way to achive this with maven-assembly? If not, what is the simplest way to achive my goal?

Comment: Have you tried to create several `<plugin>` entries for `maven-assembly-plugin` with different configurations? This will trigger this plugin twice and create two JAR files hopefully...

Comment: @dma_k Following your suggestion, trying to generate three JARs, the first two get overwritten by the last `<plugin>` configuration.

Comment: Try to play with `<finalName>` configuration option (check [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/howto.html)).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I wasn't able to solve this problem with the `maven-assembly-plugin` in a satisfying way, so I went for a different solution. I used the [onejar-maven-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/onejar-maven-plugin/):

```
<build>
  <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.dstovall</groupId>
    <artifactId>onejar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.4</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>build-first</id>
          <configuration>
            <mainClass>classpath.to.first.Main</mainClass>
            <attachToBuild>true</attachToBuild>
            <classifier>onejar</classifier>
            <filename>first-runnable.jar</filename>
          </configuration>
          <goals>
            <goal>one-jar</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>build-second</id>
          <configuration>
            <mainClass>classpath.to.second.Main</mainClass>
            <attachToBuild>true</attachToBuild>
            <classifier>onejar</classifier>
            <filename>second-runnable.jar</filename>
          </configuration>
          <goals>
            <goal>one-jar</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>

<pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
     <id>onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com</id>
     <url>http://onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo</url>
  </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: shouldn't the two `id`s in the two `execution`s be different ? My maven complains if I have the same id more than once.

Comment: @AndreHolzner: Yes, this was an error

Comment: IMHO, same thing is possible with maven-assembly-plugin. See @donal-fellows answer

Comment: different id's are required to uniquely identify  separate jars,

Comment: You should replace the plugin repository with this:

    <pluginRepository>
    <id>redhat-earlyaccess-repository</id>
    <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/earlyaccess/all/</url>
    </pluginRepository>

Comment: the url http://onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo seems to be no longer working

Answer (score 32):

You can do it. You'll need a separate execution for each artifact that you're building (i.e., give each its own id but you can leave the phase as default), and you'll need to specify the finalName and archive/manifest/mainClass *for each*.

```xml
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>build-a</id>
            <configuration>
              <archive>
                <manifest>
                  <mainClass>foobar.Aclass</mainClass>
                </manifest>
              </archive>
              <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
              </descriptorRefs>
              <finalName>foobar_a.jar</finalName>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>build-b</id>
            <configuration>
              <archive>
                <manifest>
                  <mainClass>foobar.Bclass</mainClass>
                </manifest>
              </archive>
              <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
              </descriptorRefs>
              <finalName>foobar_b.jar</finalName>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: It probably also ought to explicitly declare that the `single` goal is to be used.

Comment: from trying this solution and the one [posted here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15799254/288875), it looks like one also needs to add the `<goals>` and `<phase>` tags ?

Comment: I edited the post (waiting for peer review) to include goals and phase tags.

Comment: Would it also be possible to install them both? by adding a suffix to the artifact?

Comment: Can these two jars also be size minimised with the shade plugin?

Answer (score 19):

[The top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9126300/918858) works *if* you are not using any configuration (or any resource, for that matter) that gets bundled into your jar file (e.g., configuration for Spring Framework auto-bindings).

Fortunately, this solution also works with `maven-shade-plugin` and you don't have that aforementioned issue with `onejar-maven-plugin`.

Also,  `maven-shade-plugin` is actively being maintained as opposed to `onejar-maven-plugin` which is in the purgatory that is googlecode.

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>build-first</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
         <goal>shade</goal>
      </goals>   
      <configuration>
        <transformers>
          <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">                        
            <mainClass>classpath.to.first.Main</mainClass>
          </transformer>
        </transformers>
        <finalName>first-runnable</finalName>
      </configuration>        
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>build-second</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
         <goal>shade</goal>
      </goals>   
      <configuration>
        <transformers>
          <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">                        
            <mainClass>classpath.to.second.Main</mainClass>
          </transformer>
        </transformers>
        <finalName>second-runnable</finalName>
      </configuration>  
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This works but it also seems to backup the target JAR if it already exists, e.g. it creates original-first-runnable.jar and original-second-runnable.jar (using your example).

Answer (score 5):

To specify a little more previous answer that was very helpful to me, 
you need to add phase package and goal assembly and run mvn run clean package, pom is as follows :

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>build-a</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>firstMainClass</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                        <finalName>a.jar</finalName>
                    </configuration>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assembly</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>build-b</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>SecondMainClass</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                        <finalName>b.jar</finalName>
                    </configuration>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assembly</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Goal `assembly` is deprecated. See [plugin information](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/plugin-info.html).  
Better to use `single` instead.