# Maven Assembly plugin doesnt copy jar-with-dependences to the zip file

Tags: maven, maven-3

I do "mvn clean package" and it creates a zip file (based on my `assembly.xml`) with `snapshot.jar`, then it creates the zip file and lastly creates the `jar-with-dependencies.jar`

I think because zip file was created before `jar-with-dependencies.jar` was created, it was never copied to the zip file.

How can I force maven to copy both `snapshot.jar` and `jar-with-dependencies.jar` into the zip file (in other words, how can I force jar-with-dependencies is built first before assembly goal is invoked so that all jars would be copied to the zip file)

Here is pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mycomonay</groupId>
<artifactId>artid</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>art</name>
<description>artdescription</description>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>19.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.38</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- <plugin> <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId> 
            <version>2.4</version> <configuration> <archive> <manifestEntries> <Built-By>xyz</Built-By> 
            <Class-Path>.</Class-Path> </manifestEntries> </archive> </configuration> 
            </plugin> -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:unchecked</compilerArgument>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>

            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Built-By>abc</Built-By>
                        <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
                    </manifestEntries>
                    <manifest>
                        <!-- <addClasspath>true</addClasspath> -->

                        <mainClass>com.mycomonay.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>


                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>

                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
                <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <!-- <resources> <resource> <directory>src/main/resources</directory> </resource> 
        </resources> -->
</build>
```

Here is assembly.xml

```
           <assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
          <id>bin</id>
        <!--  <baseDirectory>/</baseDirectory> -->
            <formats>
      <format>zip</format>
          </formats>
       <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
       <fileSets>
          <fileSet>
             <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
             </fileSet>
           <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/scripts</directory>
               <outputDirectory>scripts</outputDirectory>
              <includes>
                  <include>*</include>
               </includes>
             </fileSet>
<fileSet>
        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
        <outputDirectory>bin</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>*with-dependencies.jar</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
```

Comment: You should include the `pom.xml` otherwise you can't expect people to be able to fully aid you.

Comment: added pom.xml and assembly.xml to the end of the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely separate the `single` goals into two executions (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8726969/3114959 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/15799254/3114959). 
Maven executes things in the same order as they appear in the *effective pom* (as long as the belong to the same phase) so if you specify both executions separated, you should be fine.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>create-jar-with-dependencies</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-the-zip</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

as a result, you'll see 2 executions during build:

```
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (create-jar-with-dependencies) @ artid ---
[INFO] ... some more output ...
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (make-the-zip) @ artid ---
```

the latter execution (the `make-the-zip`) can definitely include the results of the former one (the `create-jar-with-dependencies`).